# Open Layers and RouteService Layer

Tags: xml, openlayers-3, gml

I want to add to the OL3 map layer with response from RouteService such as:

> http://openls.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/route?start=9.256506,49.240011&end=8.72083,49.7606&via=&lang=de&distunit=KM&routepref=Car&weighting=Fastest&avoidAreas=&useTMC=false&noMotorways=false&noTollways=false&noUnpavedroads=false&noSteps=false&noFerries=false&instructions=false

(I took it from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService)

It contains XML with GML inside.

Is it possible to add new layer to the OL3 map using this response XML/GML ?

Comment: How do you get the response? How do you deal with CORS?

Comment: The [tag:gml] tag is [for the Game Maker Language](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283385/gml-tag-confusion), not geographic markup language.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct your url call, it will likely be in the fashion of:

```
var url = 'http://openls.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/route?start=[etc]';
  // +/-? {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'};

$.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
  var routeFeature = parser.readFeatures(response);
  someOverlay.getSource().addFeatures(routeFeature);
  });
```

where [etc] is your construct of from, to, route method, and other parameters.   Depending on how you construct [etc], be careful to [encodeURI(url)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) so the oddball characters are properly formatted.

I haven't implemented this myself yet, sorry no code, but it should be fairly straightforward.  Note* You may not have to specify INFO_FORMAT if this is how the response is already delivered.